# What is wrong with this prime factorization code in Java?

Tags: java, math, primes

I was trying to make a method to do the prime factorization of a number, and it's probably not the most efficient, but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> primeFactorize(int num) {
    ArrayList<Integer> primeFactors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt((double) num); i++) {
        if (isPrime(i) && factor(num).contains(i)) {
            primeFactors.add(i);
            num /= i;

            if (isPrime(num)) {
                primeFactors.add(num);
                break;
            }
            i = 2;
        }
    }
    return primeFactors;
}
```

It calls upon two other methods that I wrote named `factor()` and `isPrime()`, which do exactly what you would expect them to (returns an `ArrayList` of factors and either `true` or `false` depending on if the input is prime, respectively).

I went through the debugger with `num` being 12, and it worked fine for the first loop, where it added 2 to `primeFactors`. However, when it got to the top of the array again with `num` being 6 and `i` being 2, it exited the loop as if `i < Math.sqrt((double) num)` returned `false`.

But that wouldn't make sense, because the square root of 6 is a bit over 2. I also tried `(double) i < Math.sqrt((double) num)`, but it just did the same exact thing.

Can anyone see what I'm missing? Thanks for any replies.

---

EDIT: Here is my code now, thanks for the help! I know for sure I could make it more efficient, so I might do that later, but for now this is perfect.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> primeFactorize(int num) {
    ArrayList<Integer> primeFactors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int i = 2;
    while (i < Math.sqrt((double) num)) {
        if (isPrime(i) && num % i == 0) {
            primeFactors.add(i);
            num /= i;

            if (isPrime(num)) {
                primeFactors.add(num);
                break;
            }
            i = 2;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    return primeFactors;
}
```

Comment: sqrt(num), not sqrt(i). So with num=12, 6 is greater than sqrt(num)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `for` loop, the `i++` section will get called at the end of every loop. So in your code, you set `i` equal to 2. Then, the loop ends, and adds 1 to `i`, making it be 3. Then the comparison happens, and 3 is more than sqrt(6), so the loop exits.

If you want `i` to be 2 in the next iteration, you need to set it to a value so that *after* the increment operation runs it will be 2, not *before*; in this case, you should set it to 1. A better solution would be to change your code structure so it's not necessary though. [As pointed out by biziclop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977778/what-is-wrong-with-this-prime-factorization-code-in-java/38977877#comment65308693_38977877), a `while` loop will let you decide whether or not to increment, and will avoid this problem.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with i++, can't believe I missed that lol, thanks!

Comment: General advice: don't use `for` loops if you manipulate the loop variable from within the loop body. Use `while`, it'll make your code a lot clearer. Keep `for` for simple loops between two points.

Comment: Why use a function`factor()` ? You just want to know whether the current value of `i` is a factor of `num`, so `(num%i)==0` will suffice.

Comment: I'm not actually sure why I didn't think of that, thanks for that as well lol

Answer (score 3):

Since you already accepted an answer I assume your problem is solved. The thing I want to point out is that casting integers to doubles is generally a bad idea if there is another way. Therefore I want to show you the below implementation, which doesn't use floating-point arithmetic. Also I think it's a bad idea to check whether or not `num` is a prime number, because this slows down the algorithm. Moreover if `num % i == 0` evaluates to true, `i` is always a prime number, thus the `isPrime(i)` check is superfluous and also slows down your algorithm.

```
List <Integer> primeFactors(int n) {
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; ++i) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            factors.add(i);
            n /= i ;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        factors.add(n);
    }
    return factors ;
}
```

Comment: Really nice code, thanks! It's always good to hear  about how I could make my code more efficient, considering as a high schooler that's the one thing you don't really learn too much about lol

Comment: You are welcome, maybe you (or me) should do a runtime comparison ;). btw up-votes are always welcome :)

Comment: i tried to upvote like 5 things but I don't think i have enough reputation yet lol

Comment: You could speed up the algorithm by treating factor 2 separately at the start and then changing the loop to step 2 each time from 3: `for (int i = 3; i <= n / i; i += 2)`  That will save testing any even trial factors, except 2.

Comment: True, but you can also do every 6 numbers, if you add some more checks. So much clutter do you want to add?